# The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) int, Stream<Integer>

Tags: java, java-8

While refactoring this code

```
for (String s : str) {
    for (String st : str) {
        if (st.length() > s.length()) {
            System.out.println(st + " " + st.length());
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

to functional, with this statement

```
names.filter(t -> t.length() > names.map(x -> x.length())).findFirst().toString();
```

I'm getting a compile time error :

> The operator `>` is undefined for the argument type(s) `int`, `Stream<Integer>`

How to solve that?

Comment: How is the first snippet related to the second snippet? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: actually I am trying to find the biggest string from `Stream<String>` and not sure how to solve that

Comment: And, seriously: you wrote up a decent question; and you just started here. So do your soul a favor and *change* your nick name. Nobody should call himself "dumb". It might sound "funny" on the surface; but in the end, every time you see that nick ... well, you send a message to your inner self; and not a nice message that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is self explanatory - `t.length()` is an `int` and `names.map(x -> x.length())` is a `Stream<Integer>`. You can't apply the `>` operator to an `int` and a `Stream<Integer>`.

To find the longest `String`, you can sort the `String`s by length in descending order and take the first element from the sorted `Stream` :

```
String longest = names.sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b.length(), a.length()))
                      .findFirst()
                      .get();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
someStrings.stream().max((s1, s2) -> Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length())).get()
```

or even shorter:

```
someStrings.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).get()
```

(which should probably a win over "sorting" performance wise)

And hint: even when it is just an example: using names like "s", "st", and "str" is just confusing the hell out of your readers. Don't do that. Ever.